# Merging two listviews into one using adapter in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I'm trying to merge 2 listviews into one using an adapter, the   "ContatosTelefoneModel" is working fine, it is showing all the telephones in the list, the problem is the emails, it is showing only the last value of the array, I'll add some images to explain it better:

[image]   I have an array with 4 emails, steve1, steve2, steve3, and steve4, and I'm only getting steve4, I very, very noob to android development, I'd like to Know how to show the emails array properly.

```
public class TelefoneListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

    private ArrayList<ContatosTelefoneModel> listD;

    private ArrayList<ContatosEmailModel> email;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private Context mContext;

    public TelefoneListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContatosTelefoneModel> listData, ArrayList<ContatosEmailModel> emails) {
        this.listD = listData;
        this.email = emails;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listD.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listD.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tel_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numero);
            holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tipo);
            holder.emailView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.email);
            holder.IdTelefone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TelefoneID);


            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

            ContatosTelefoneModel newsItem = listD.get(position);
            holder.headlineView.setText(newsItem.getNumero());
            holder.reportedDateView.setText(newsItem.getTipo());




        for(int x=0; x<email.size(); x++) {

           ContatosEmailModel mContatosEmailModel = email.get(x);
            holder.emailView.setText(mContatosEmailModel.getEmail());




        }

       return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView headlineView;
        TextView reportedDateView;
        TextView emailView;
        TextView IdTelefone;
        TextView ContatoCliente;

    }
}
```

Models:

```
public class ContatosEmailModel implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private int id_rm;
    private String email;
    private String tipo;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId_rm() {
        return id_rm;
    }

    public void setId_rm(int id_rm) {
        this.id_rm = id_rm;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ContatosEmailModel{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", id_rm=" + id_rm +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", tipo='" + tipo + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public class ContatosTelefoneModel implements Serializable{

    private int id;
    private int id_rm;
    private String numero;
    private String tipo;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId_rm() {
        return id_rm;
    }

    public void setId_rm(int id_rm) {
        this.id_rm = id_rm;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ContatosTelefoneModel{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", id_rm=" + id_rm +
                ", numero='" + numero + '\'' +
                ", tipo='" + tipo + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using for loop here???

> ```
>     for(int x=0; x<email.size(); x++) {
>        ContatosEmailModel mContatosEmailModel = email.get(x);
>         holder.emailView.setText(mContatosEmailModel.getEmail());
>     }
> ```

Just do same as you are doing for headline view and reportedDateView

Change your this code :

> holder.emailView.setText(this.email.get(position).getEmail());

```
    for(int x=0; x<email.size(); x++) {

       ContatosEmailModel mContatosEmailModel = email.get(x);
        holder.emailView.setText(mContatosEmailModel.getEmail());
    }
```

**to this :**

```
holder.emailView.setText(mContatosEmailModel.getEmail());
```

Comment: the size of "email" is not equal to the size of the listD array

Comment: Then you must use model class to hold the values and keep record of this, that what rows have emails or not. Have you ever worked on model classes? 
**If not** Then see [this example](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter), In this example, weather.java is a model class to hold title and icon values

Comment: Yes, I'm working with models, I've just added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

If both arrays are the same size, then remove your "for" loop here:

```
  for(int x=0; x<email.size(); x++) {
      ContatosEmailModel mContatosEmailModel = email.get(x);
        holder.emailView.setText(mContatosEmailModel.getEmail());
  }
```

This is a problem because each time an Item is displayed, you are only getting the last one. You could change it like this:

```
  //for(int x=0; x<email.size(); x++) {
      ContatosEmailModel mContatosEmailModel = email.get(position);
        holder.emailView.setText(mContatosEmailModel.getEmail());
  //}
```

I would recommend putting them into an abject array that holds both values in the same position, though.

Or you could do some kind of matching - but how do you know which email goes with the proper name? In that case, I have answered your question about why this is happening, but you don't explain where you get the data or how to match emails to each Telephone number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you show me how would I do that, put the into an objet array? cause they are not the same size

Comment: Matching email to the telephone numbers is a very different problem. You have two sets of data that need merging - and that depends on the data you have and the logic you want to use to merge them. It is not an Adapter problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm working with models, I've just added it to the question